# Under the covers, how are RefreshTokens kept track of? (ASP.NET Owin/OAuth2)

Tags: asp.net, security, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin

Even if we stop the API, or shut down the whole machine, resuming it still keeps track of the refresh tokens that have been issued to the clients. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is typically stored in a database by the authorization server.

It is also common for mobile UI clients to store them in OS secure storage.

It is also common for server side web apps to include the refresh token in an auth cookie so that it remains available across requests.

Your API should only ever receive access tokens - and should not know anything about refresh tokens.

I'd need to know more about your specific scenario to be able to advise further.

Comment: It's a simple ASP.NET project, with its own implementation of OAuth2 using OWIN I think? (I define `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` and pass the defined object to `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` (app is `IAppBuilder` object, inside the `Configuration` method of every ASP.NET application.

Comment: I've implemented the parts I need, it's not a full re-implementation. Nowhere in my code do I implement logic for how the tokens are handled. Yes I have a repository where I save them, but that's not the back-bone of the actual ASP.NET thing that keeps track of them. Why? Picture the following: You have the very same ASP.NET application. I authenticate myself on your instance, all's good - that token is saved to the database. If I get that refresh token (from db) and request a new access token from the token endpoint on **my** PC instance of the application - `invalid_grant` will be returned.

Comment: Why that happens? Because obviously the refresh tokens generated by **your** ASP.NET project/application, are only valid for **your** application. It's as if passing a refresh token from a different Authorization server/application, like for example Microsoft, and expect it to return any claims/information.

All of this implies that the application somewhere and somehow stores these refresh tokens as a reference, internally, and not memory-wise, as even if the computer is shut-down, it still keeps track of them all. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah - I see - understand your scenario now - feels like the back end will not use database storage by default. Who is the API client? Feels like a cookie issue - where the auth server maybe just checks cookie encryption + expiry then treats it as a trusted refresh token based on cookie data.

Comment: ASP.NET is the API client if that's what you meant asking (It's literally just an API, no attached web servers -- authentication is done via the resource owner password credentials grant). Also, I believe it's not tied to a cookie, as using Postman to send a request with the required key-value pairs for a new access token (with a given refresh token) works, without any additional cookies or context. That's how I understood the "peculiarity" with these refresh tokens - ones generated by my API work, while the others from the same API, but hosted on a different machine do not.